# unable to boot with NAS disk attached

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, hard-disk

My cheap Zyxel NAS died and I have a 2TB disk from it. When I plug that disk to my Ubuntu server, it does not boot.

```
sata_0 = boot disk
sata_1 = data disk
```

upto these two only system boots fine.

when i connect 2TB disk to sata_3, it comes to boot stage (select image to boot), but then it halts.

Here is the error:

[image]

I have another new 2TB disk, when i attach that disk, it boots fine but does not list the disk in df command.

What is the problem here? OS is 14.04 (its old sorry)

Thank you,
RJ

Comment: What does the entire error message say? Does the system boot when the drive is connected to a different SATA port? Does it work an another computer?

Comment: One (or more) of the partitions on the problematical disk has the `BOOT` flag set, but no bootable system on the partition.

Comment: `df` does not list (unmounted) disk. Use `lsblk` instead. It sounds like a misunderstanding + the drive from the dead NAS is probably somewhat dead as well and is causing problem to the SATA controller, which prevents other working disks from being populated to the system.

Comment: @waltinator it was way past the stage in which partition boot flag matters

Comment: @waltinator with NAS disk attached, the control 'was' going to GRUB and booting from right disk, but there is something about the NAS disk which halted booting at the screenshot.   Also, fdisk -l showed the new disk just fine when old NAS disk was removed and new 2TB disk was attached.  Therefore the prob seems to be only with old-NAS-disk, How can I inquire that disk?

Comment: Also, when the boot disk is Ubuntu LTS, where from this busybox is coming I am not sure...????

Comment: Initramfs. See the last line on your screen.